# How to get values from checked checkboxes in controller?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

How to get values from checked checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All data is stored in `$this->data` (readonly) or `$this->request->data` (can be modified) after a form submit. Wrap the aforementioned `$this->data` in a `debug()` call to see the structure of the returned data. It will probably look roughly like the following:

```
  array(
    'ModelName' => array(
      'name' => 'value',
      'name' => 'value'
    )
  )
```

Comment: Note to OP: if you're *not* using the FormHelper to create the checkboxes, make sure to prefix the input's name with 'data', i.e., `name="data[my_checkbox]"` would show up in `$this->request->data["my_checkbox"];`.